# How can I solve ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating input form with rails api and I tested then rails was returned me this error.

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'support' for Product.):
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:36:in `create'

Parameters: {"product"=>{"maker"=>"", "model"=>"", "price"=>"", "method"=>"", "support"=>"", "size"=>"", "agency"=>""}, "use "=>{"use"=>"qq"}}
```

Actually I input data to simple form below and then sent to every data to each tables through ProductUse model, of course add product_id and use_id to ProductUse model.Someone know about this please tell me.

```
        <input type="string" name="product[maker]"  placeholder="maker">
        <input type="string" name="product[model]"  placeholder="model">
        <input type="string" name="product[price]"  placeholder="price">
        <input type="string" name="product[method]"  placeholder="method">
        <input type="string" name="product[support]"  placeholder="support">
        <input type="string" name="product[size]" placeholder="size">
        <input type="string" name="product[agency]" placeholder="agency">
        <input type="string" name="use[use]" placeholder="use">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :product_uses
      has_many :uses, :through => :product_uses
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :uses
end
class Use < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_uses
    has_many :products, :through => :product_uses
end
class ProductUse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :use
end




def create
   @product = Product.new(product_params)
     if [@product,@uses].save
       render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product
     else
       render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end
end



  def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:maker, :model, :method, :price, :support, :size, :agency)
   end
```

Comment: Could you post your controller `create` method?

Comment: I post by means of create method. I just added code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if you created the `support` attribute in the Database.
It should be in your migration file for product.
Or you can go to the **rails console** and type:

```
Product.columns.map(&:name)
```

which should print all the columns your model has automatically mapped to attributes.

Comment: What a stupid mistake I had. I solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: no problem. please mark this as the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'support' for Product.)`:
That is Product has no 'support' attribute or has error 'support',check a word spelling error.